# Why is $R[X,Y]/(X^2-Y^3)$ isomorphic to $\{\sum a_iT^i\in R[T] \; : \; a_1=0\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring (commutative, with unit). Show that $A=\{\sum a_iT^i\in R[T] \; : \; a_1=0\}$ is a subring of $R[T]$ and isomorphic to $R[X][Y]/(X^2-Y^3)$.

Of course, I'm trying to find a ring homomorphism of $R[X][Y]$ into $R[T]$ with image $A$ and kernel $(X^2-Y^3)$. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: One of the frequent confusions in this sort of problem is the duplicate usage of $X$ in both rings.  This prolem would be more obvious if you had expressed $A$ as a subset of $R[Z]$ rather than $R[X]$.

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, you're right. Should I change it? If I do, it will make lhf's answer incomprehensible.

Comment: I wasn't necessarily recommending changing it, just noting that the reason the solution doesn't seem as obvious as it is is due to this.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130534

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about $X \mapsto T^3$ and $Y \mapsto T^2$?

Comment: Thank you. I see that $A$ is the image, but not yet why every element of the kernel is a multiple of $X^2-Y^3$.

Comment: @Stefan, you need to consider the positive integer solutions of $3i+2j=k$ for each $k$. You go from one solution to another by adding or subtracting $2$ from $i$ while subtracting or adding $3$ to $j$. Then you can collect terms and they'll all be multiples of $X^2-Y^3$. Do a few cases...

Comment: @Stefan, in other words, it's all about knowing the shape of the general solution of $3i+2j=k$.

Comment: Got it! Thanks again.

Comment: @Stefan, for fun, consider now the general case $R[X,Y]\to R[T]$, with $X \mapsto T^a$ and $Y \mapsto T^b$. What is the image? What is the kernel?

Comment: Can $\mathbb{N}a+\mathbb{N}b$ be further simplified?

Comment: @Stefan, it's related to the [Frobenius problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_problem). The set $\mathbb{N}a+\mathbb{N}b$ contains all numbers greater than a certain limit and some less than this limit, but I'm not sure the smaller set is easy to describe.

Answer (score 2):

If you choose a basis for $R[X][Y]/(X^2-Y^3)$ (as a free $R$-module), you will have a clearer image of what it looks like. 
For example you can show that $(1,Y,Y^2,Y^3,\ldots,X,XY,XY^2,XY^3,\ldots)$ is one possible basis.

And then look at what is the image of the basis under the isomorphism.