# $K[x,y]/\langle x^2-y^3\rangle \cong K[t^2,t^3]$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm stuck with this (should be easy) computation. I started by considering the most natural map $K[x,y] \to K[t^2,t^3]$ which is the one that sends $x \mapsto t^3$ and $y \mapsto  t^2$, and then extend by linearity. the map is easily seen to be surjective and factors through the quotient. The point is that I cannot find a way to show that the induced map is injective.. If I try to write down a general polynomial in two variables which is sent to zero I lose myself in the computations. Are there some other methods to show such claim?

Answer (score 2):

Actually the explicit computation is very easy:

Take a polynomial $f \in K[x,y]$ satisfying $f(t^3,t^2)=0$. By replacing each occurence of $x^2$ by $y^3$, we obtain $f = g(y)+xh(y) \mod (x^2-y^3)$ with some polynomials $g,h \in K[Y]$.

Now we have $0 = g(t^2)+t^3h(t^2)$. By looking at the degrees, we easily see $g=h=0$, hence the result.