# An approach to proving that $\Bbb{Q}[x,y]/(x^3-y^2)$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Q}[t^2,t^3]$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

I have to prove that $\Bbb{Q}[x,y]/(x^3-y^2)$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Q}[t^2,t^3]$.

My approach: Let us consider $t^2$ and $t^3$ as separate variables $x$ and $y$. The relations that hold for them are $x^{3n}=y^{2n}$. Hence, $\Bbb{Q}[t^2,t^3]$ would be isomorphic to $\Bbb{Q}[x,y](x^3-y^2,x^6-y^4,x^9-y^6,\dots)=\Bbb{Q}[x,y]/(x^3-y^2)$.

My problem: How do I prove that $x^{3n}=y^{2n}$ are the only relations that hold for $x=t^2$ and $y=t^3$?

Comment: It means nothing to "consider" them as separate variables. Evaluation at $(t^2,t^3)$ is a ring homomorphism $\mathbf Q[x,y] \rightarrow \mathbf Q[t^2,t^3]$ that is obviously surjective. Prove the kernel is $(x^3-y^2)$, i.e., for a polynomial $f(x,y)$ in $\mathbf Q[x,y]$ you have $f(t^2,t^3) = 0$ only if $f(x,y)$ is divisible by $x^3-y^2$. Note that your list of relations $x^{3n}=y^{2n}$ is woefully incomplete; those are just the *easiest* relations. They are definitely not all of them. The point of computing the kernel of that map is to show all relations are consequences of $x^3=y^2$.

Comment: This is certainly a (multiple) duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$K[x,y]/\langle x^2-y^3\rangle \cong K[t^2,t^3]$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130534/kx-y-langle-x2-y3-rangle-cong-kt2-t3)

Answer (score 1):

Define a map $\varphi:\mathbb{Q}[x,y]\to\mathbb{Q}[t],\ x\mapsto t^2, y\mapsto t^3$. It's clear that $\text{im}\varphi=\mathbb{Q}[t^2,t^3]$, so it suffices to show that $\ker\varphi=(x^3-y^2)$. Apparently $\ker\varphi\supseteq(x^3-y^2)$, to prove the reverse containing relation, for any $f(x,y)\in\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$, divede it by $x^3-y^2$ and we get a remainder $r(x,y)=ya(x)+b(x)$. If $\varphi(f)=f(t^2,t^3)=0$, then $r(t^2,t^3)=t^3a(t^2)+b(t^2)=0$ (comparing the order of each monomial term of $r$ after the substitution), which forces that $a=b=0$, thus the conclusion.