# Is $\mathbb{R}[x^2,x^3]=\{f=\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i\in\mathbb{R}[x]:a_1=0\}$ is Euclidean Domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, euclidean-domain

> Is  $\mathbb{R}[x^2,x^3]=\{f=\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i\in\mathbb{R}[x]:a_1=0\}$ an  Euclidean Domain ?

My answer : I know that  it is integral domain  ,by  theorem R  is  integral domain then  $\Bbb R[x]$ is  integral domain.

Now  I am confused that  here how  can I claimed  that it  is  Euclidean  domain or not ?

Any hints...

Please help  me.

Comment: Is the ideal generated by $x^2$ and $x^3$ principal?

Comment: It is not even a UFD : $x^6 = x^3 \cdot x^3 = x^2 \cdot x^2 \cdot x^2$, and the factors are irreducible elements.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknownit is $ 0+ a_1x + a_2 x^2+ a_3x^3 + a_4x^4 +a_5x^5 +a_6x^6 $  ...by this  i can say No,

Comment: @Watson.very  simple  idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may know, any euclidean domain is a PID, and any PID is a UFD. But your ring $R$ is not even a UFD : $x^6 = x^3 \cdot x^3 = x^2 \cdot x^2 \cdot x^2$, and the factors can be checked to be irreducible elements.

Your ring is isomorphic to $\Bbb R[X,Y] / (Y^2-X^3)$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38496/why-is-rx-y-x2-y3-isomorphic-to-sum-a-iti-in-rt-a-1-0)), so you may find [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/880433/is-mathbbcx-y-y2-x3-a-pid) or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466885). As mentioned there, $R$ is not even *integrally closed*, for $a := x^3 / x^2 \in \mathrm{Frac}(R)$ is integral over $R$ (since $a^2 - x^2 = 0$), but $a \not\in R$.

Comment: thanks.. @watson